# Callback Issue in Request js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request

I'm facing an issue regarding callback in Request js function. Given below is my code.

```
function getContent(address, result, callback){
    request(address, function (err, response, body) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        }
    });
    callback(null, result); 
}
```

Now when i run given code my callback is called and then my request function is hit. I want to execute my callback after execution of console.log(body) line. Kindly give me your suggestions about this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback() function should be inside the callback for the request. That ways, only when the request is completed would it get called.

```
function getContent(address, result, callback){
request(address, function (err, response, body) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        callback(null, result); 
    }
});
}
```